# Calculation of complex exponentiation

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

I understand that:

$a^{ib}$ = $Cos[bLn(a)]+iSin[bLn(a)]$

Mathematica calculates
N[$7^{6i}$] = $0 + 117649i$ $\quad$ and $\quad$ N[Cos[6Log[7]] + iSin[6Log[7]]] = $0.628704848492136 - 0.7776440146252527i$

I would expect '$0 + 117649i$' and '$0.628704848492136 - 0.7776440146252527i$' to differ by a period of $\pi$, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

That is, 0 $\neq$ 0.628704848492136 $\pm$ $n\pi$

What am I not understanding correctly?  Thank you.

Comment: What's $N[\bullet]$?

Comment: I get exactly the same result $N\left[7^{6 i}\right]=0.628705\, -0.777644 i$  and  $N[\cos (6 \log (7))+i \sin (6 \log (7))]=0.628705\, -0.777644 i$
code is N[7^(6 I)] and N[Cos[6 Log[7]] + I Sin[6 Log[7]]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expectation is wrong because you are not respecting operator precedence:

> `N[7^6i]` is interpreted a $N[(7^6)i]= (7^6) i = 117649 i$

If you use $N[7^{6i}] =$ `N[7^(6i)]` you get the coinciding result

> $ N[7^{6i}] = \cos(6 \ln 7)+i\sin(6\ln 7)=0.6287048484921367- 0.7776440146252522 i$